# How to detect if a player is in a Taiga biome?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any command that can detect if a player is in a taiga biome?

Comment: I couldn't find anything to check the biome, a player is in.
Might be worth a feature request on http://bugs.mojang.com/

Comment: No. Your best bet is checking for the environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually test for a player in a specific biome, but you can scan an area for (a) player(s). Simply enter the following command. `/testfor @p[0,64,0,20]` Be sure to substitute the first three numbers for the center coordinates of the Tagia biome, and the fourth number with the radius of the area you want the player to be detected in. You can also have several command blocks to adapt to a stranger shaped biome. One you have placed the command block, connect it to a [repeating circuit](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clock_circuit/Repeater_Clocks) and place a redstone comparator facing away from the command block, and on the other side of the comparator, place the command block holding the command you want to be executed when the player enters the biome. 
 Hope this helps!
-A

Comment: The `type` parameter does not function for `@p`, and if it did the correct input for targeting players would be "Player", not "player".

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It's been awhile since i've used the `/testfor` command on a player. ;)

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute if entity @p[x=0,y=64,z=0,distance=..20]`